# Almost everywhere additive function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

A measurable $ f:R \to R $ satisfying

$f (x+y)= f (x) + f (y)$ for almost every pair $(x, y) $ if and only if$ f (x) =cx $ for almost every $ x$. True or false ?

If $ f $ is locally integrable I think it is true because (not pretty though);

$ g (u) =\int_0^1f (tu) dt $

$g(u)=\frac {\int_0^uf (x) dx}{u}$ if $u \ge 0$

$g(u)=-\frac {\int_u^0f (x) dx}{u}$ if $u < 0$

$ g (u) $ is continuous except possibly at $ u=0$ (actually I'll show $ g$ is continuous everywhere).Now let $ A \in R^2$ be the set on which $ f $ is additive .

$ (a, b ), (c, d),(\delta,\alpha) \in A $  and $ a, b, c, d,\delta,\alpha \neq 0$

continuity of $g(u)$ :$\lim_{\delta\to 0}g(a+\delta)=g(a)$

define $ h (t, x, y)=|f(tx+ty)-f (tx)-f (ty)|$

$h$ is measurable over $ t, x, y,t×x,t×y,x×y,t×x×y $ because we can always find a sequence of continuous functions $\{m_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}m_n(x)=f(x) $ae in $R$:$\lim_{n \to \infty}|m_n(tx+ty)-m_n (tx)-m_n (ty)|=h(t,x,y)$ ae in $R^1,R^2,R^3$ . Clearly $m_n(t,x,y)$ is jointly continuous and therefore the  limit $h$ is measurable.

$ h =0$ for almost every pair $(x, y)   $

$\int_{t×x×y}h dtdxdy= \int_{t×x×y}h d\mu=\int_{t×x×y}h dxdydt=0$ , this implies for almost all pair $(\delta,\alpha) $  , $f(t\alpha+t\delta)=f(t\alpha)+f(t\delta) $for almost every $t \in R$

:$\lim_{\delta\to 0}g(\alpha+\delta)=g(\alpha)+\lim_{\delta\to 0}g(\delta)=g(\alpha)$ , which implies $\lim_{\delta\to 0}g(\delta)=0$ and by continuity we can find a pair $(e,i) \in A^c,e,i\neq 0$, such that $|\delta-e|+|\alpha-i|<\delta,|g(\delta)-g(e)|<\epsilon$

so for a pair $(e,i) \in A^c,e,i\neq 0$ :$\lim_{|e|\to 0}g(e)=0$

$\lim_{b \to a} g (a-b)=\lim_{c\to d} g (c-d)=0$:$\lim_{b \to a} g (a-b)=g(a)+\lim_{b \to a}g(-b)=g(a)+g(-a)=0$

it follows that $g(-a)=-g(a)$ and by continuity $g(-a')=-g(a')$
$ g (0)=g (a - a)=g(a)+g(-a)=0$

So $ g(u) $ approaches zero as $ |u| \to 0$

given any pair $(a', b') $ in $ A^c$ there is a pair $(a,b)$ in $ A$ such that $|a-a'|<\delta,|b-b'|<\delta,$$ |g (a+b)-g (a'+b')|<\epsilon,|g (a)+g (b)-g (a')-g (b')|<\epsilon$
 where $\epsilon, \delta > 0$

Therefore $ g $ is continuous everywhere and satisfy $ g (x+y)=g (x)+g (y) $

Continuous solution of Cauchy functional equation$ g (u) = ku $

$ ku^2 =\int_0^uf (x) dx , u \ge 0$

$ ku^2 =-\int_u^0 f (x) dx , u <0$

which shows $ f (u)=2ku $ ae

Comment: Your argument for locally integrable case is incomplete. Since $g$ is not known to be continuous at $0$ you cannot conclude that $g$ satisfies Cauchy's equation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it is continuous everywhere. I added the details.

Comment: The result for locally integrable $ f $ is true. See http://www.bdim.eu/item?fmt=pdf&id=RLIN_1990_9_1_2_139_0